# Find minimum difference between two vectors with numba

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, jit, numba

I've tried to optimize searching for minimum value between two `numpy` vectors with `numba`. There is speed up and result is correct until I use `prange` and `parallel=True` option. I understand that the issue is in sharing variables `min_val`, `tmp`, `min_val_idx_a`, `min_val_idx_b` during parallel execution (maybe with parallel threads). Is there way to overcome the problem and use `numba` in with `parallel=True` option ? (which makes my simple code 300x faster)

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, int32, void, double, prange

@jit(void(double[:], double[:], int32), nopython=True, parallel=True)
def lowest_value_numba(a, b, n): 
    
    # initialization
    min_val_idx_a, min_val_idx_b = 0, 0
    min_val = tmp = np.abs(a[0]-b[0])
    
    for i in prange(n):
#         print(i)
        for j in prange(i, n):
            tmp = np.abs(a[i]-b[j])
            
            if(tmp < min_val):
                min_val = tmp            
                min_val_idx_a = i
                min_val_idx_b = j
    print(min_val, min_val_idx_a, min_val_idx_b)
                
n = int(1e4)
a = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=n)
b = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=n)

# setting min value by setting the same valu efor a[n-1] and b[n-1] 
a[n-1], b[n-1] = 1, 1

%timeit -n 1 -r 1 lowest_value_numba(a, b, n)
```

output which is incorrect (it should be `0.0 9999 9999`):

```
0.23648058275546968 0 0
223 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

but for compilation with `parallel=False` output is correct (last values are most close to each other):

```
0.0 9999 9999
65 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I was able to make this work with parallel by replacing `min_val_idx_a, min_val_idx_b = 0, 0`  with a numpy array of two zero values. Then I updated the values in the array. However, trying to run timeit with multiple runs gave inconsistent results... so I don't think this is the full answer.

Comment: @jakub thanks, for me results are consistent

Comment: @jakub sorry, there are some errors : `0.0 9999 9999`,
`2.2752791872804323e-08 1581 5090`,
`0.0 9999 9999`,
`0.0 9999 9999`

Comment: The [numba parallel documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html?highlight=prange#explicit-parallel-loops) has helpful notes. It states that "the user is required to make sure that the loop does not have cross iteration dependencies except for supported reductions." It might be possible to reframe the original problem in terms of those supported reductions, because the current implementation has cross-iteration dependencies.

Comment: @jakub so no nesting prange is allowed ? but even then I see the same error

Comment: The issue, I think, is that you are potentially overwriting the index on each iteration. This is not a reduction method, like `+=`. In the case of loops that do `+=`, numba can compute multiple sums in parallel, and finally sum all of those sums. In the current problem, the index is being overwritten. Do you see the difference? How would the parallel threads (not sure if they're threads) know how to reduce the values they computed. Seems like a race condition.

Comment: Not related to Numba issues: Why are you using `for j in prange(i, n)`? If both vectors are different you should compare all value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the issues commented about cross iteration dependencies if you parallelize by rows. For example:

```
from numba import jit, int32, double, prange
from numba.types import Tuple

@jit(Tuple([double, int32, int32])(double[:], double[:], int32),
     nopython=True, parallel=True)
def lowest_value_numba(a, b, n):

    min_dif = np.empty_like(a)
    min_j = np.empty((n,), dtype=int32)

    for i in prange(n):
        diff = np.abs(a[i] - b)
        min_j[i] = j = np.argmin(diff)
        min_dif[i] = diff[j]

    i = np.argmin(min_dif)
    j = min_j[i]
    min_val = min_dif[i]

    return min_val, i, j
```

Results are consistent with your implementation (tested with `parallel=False` and `for j in prange(n)`) and with the brute force Numpy approach:

```
def lowest_value_numpy(a, b):
    diff = np.abs(np.atleast_2d(a).T - np.atleast_2d(b))
    indices = np.unravel_index(diff.argmin(), diff.shape)
    return diff[indices], *indices
```

Comment: I think you can compare only the upper part of the matrix as the OP does. This is probably faster and the result should be the same, although it makes the implementation a bit more complex. In practice, It means `b` could be replaced by `b[i:]` and indices incremented to take the shift into account.

Comment: That's true when you compare a vector with itself [A,B,C]->[AB,AC,BC].
But in this case both vectors are different, so it's necessary to go trough all possible pairs [A,B,C]x[D,E,F]->[AD,AE,AF,BD,BE,BF,CD,CE,CF]

Answer (score 2):

To complete the great answer of @aerobiomat, Numba does *not currently support* **explicit/inferred** *min/max parallel reductions* (at the date of writing -- for Numba 0.52).
To quote the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html#supported-operations):

> Binary operators: `+ - * / /? % | >> ^ << & ** //` [...] 
> The user is required to make sure that the loop does not have cross iteration dependencies except for **supported reductions**. [...] 
> A reduction is inferred automatically if a variable is updated by a **binary function/operator** using its previous value in the loop body. [...] 
> The compiler may **not detect** such cases and then a **race condition** would occur.

As a result, your code is ill-formed and a race condition appear.

Alternatively, you can produce the matrix of all the values and use the implicitly parallel `np.argmin` with `parallel=True` but the solution provided by @aerobiomat should be faster (as it does not generate a big temporary matrix).